# Use a KD Tree to search in fewer dimensions than the cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'd like to search my 3D (`xyz`) for point cloud using a 2D (`xy`) criteria.

i.e. "Find all the points near x=2 AND y=4 regardless of their Z coordinate"

Conceptually, I thought I could solve this by creating a KD tree that only considered x & y, but I can't seem to find anyway with the PCL tools to do that.

Is there a good (already written) way to do this?  Or will I have to implement my own [likely slower] Kd tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were thinking about a KD Tree, then you are having some limits on the retrieved points either by number of closest or their distance.

In your case, that should be the distance, So, then you get the point between `(x-dx, x+dx) and (y-dy, y+dy)`.

One way to do that in pcl is using [pcl::getPointsInBox()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/group__common.html#gab831a44b375fa7e6bada740d1d17e247)

> Get a set of points residing in a box given its bounds.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> cloud the point cloud data message
> min_pt    the minimum bounds
> max_pt    the maximum bounds
> indices   the resultant set of point indices residing in the box
> ```

So, if you want to get points between x(1.25, 1.75) and y(2.25, 2.75), you have to create the two MinMax points as follows :

```
PointMin(1.25, 2.25, min_z)
PointMax(1.75, 2.75, max_z)
```

`min_z & max_z` could be set arbitrarly low and high as(-15, 40), granting that you'll be getting all the points with the specified (x,y) range without regard to (z)

Comment: Would this be as fast as a KD tree should be?

Answer (score 0):

6 year late to the party I know but suppose you could create a copy of you cloud where all z vals are = 1 (effectively projecting all points into a common plane) and make a 3D kdtree from this. Indexes should be valid in original cloud.

Comment: I'm a few companies past that question now, but I likely would have been concerned about the memory usage in that case.  These were some pretty big point clouds so duplicating them would have been a lot.