# Determine whether a point is above a mesh surface with PCL

Tags: c++11, 3d, point-cloud-library

How can I determine whether a point is above an irregular mesh/surface in PCL?

I have one cloud of points that I would like to convert to a surface/mesh (not sure which terminology I should use.)  Think of it as an irregular ground plane.  For example:

[image: Example of random surface]

This just shows that the surface can be sort of random, even have holes in it where data wasn't available.

Now, I have another point cloud, and I'd like to be able to filter out all the points that are below this surface.

The way I've been converting my points to a surface was by following the [Fast triangulation of unordered point clouds tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php).

If I can do this without converting the points to a surface, that would be great too.  I'm new at this so I can easily imagine I'm going about this all wrong.

When I tried using straight point clouds, sparsity became a big issue.  For example, in the image below, I generated a dense surface of points, and to filter the other cloud, used used `getPointsInBox()` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352278/1861346)) to search beneath the points.  But as you can see, it fails with sparsity (the blue points circled in black.)

If I could create a more-or-less continuous mesh grid of points from my original points, the `getPointsInBox()` method would work quite well, but I also haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

[image: Denser point cloud showing a surface]

Comment: A quick question, the blue points in black circles are the ones that are beneath the holes ? and what exactly do you mean by sparsity ?

Comment: Those blue points are examples of points that are above the red "plane", but weren't detected because there are no red points directly below them.  By sparsity, visually speaking I mean holes in the red "plane" above - basically an area where points are missing for one reason or another.

Comment: In your graph I see points either between the XZ plane and your surface (points **below** ground), or above your surface (points **above** ground). Am I wrong?.
Is there any possibility of having points below the XZ plane or outside of this plane in the X/Z direction? If the answer is no, I have an idea that could be valid for your issue.

Comment: In a real use case, there should never be any points below.  They exist here because I generated the points randomly, and also wanted to make sure anything below would be removed.  I'd love to hear your idea though (sorry for the late reply, was on vacation for 2 weeks)  My solution so far was to "up-sample" my points.  Not enough characters to fully describe it, but basically I use the down-sampled above-ground points returned by [ProgressiveMorphologicalFilter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/progressive_morphological_filtering.php) to find the non-filtered above-ground points